# Is it image or can we develop it as drawable?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view

**I want to develop same UI like this.**

In this UI you can see yellow shaded style on right up corner. I want to ask that how can I develop this type of asset in android?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do both or even [import an SVG](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#svg) which is usually my preferred way. On the link i passed you will see examples of all different methods so I will just give you quick summary here.

If you decide for image-based formats like JPEG,PNG... you will have to import it multiple times for different screen sizes in order not to lose sharpness which will take more storage space

If you decide for vector based graphics like Xml drawables from android or SVG, you end up with more flexibility and programmability of your graphic and less storage space needed. However it can decrease performance of the app if graphic is complicated (not in your case yours is super simple) because it uses computing power to render the vectors instead of just showing file from storage

Comment: Thanks it helped me now i got how they make curve designs on back on the page.

Comment: Please accept answer then, glad I could help

Comment: I don't know why my this question was degraded?